# Chrome: Print preview differs from simulate CSS media print

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, print-css

I am having an issue when I print my page in Chrome 26 where tables appear with grey background colour.

When I view the page in chrome with simulated CSS media print it looks fine

[image: in browser]

[image: when printing]

When printing in Safari everything works fine.
Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: You are defining that there should be no grey background in the Print Media declaration, right?

Comment: Can we see some CSS code?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am using bootstrap css as is, with no mods. I am not explicitly declaring no grey background. Do I have to do this? I tried background-color:blue; but the table still appears grey in the print preview

Comment: I have the same issue with margins. FF and IE print correctly. chrome emulation also. but chrome print output differs.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution:
Add this to your print css

```
* {transition: none !important}
```

See: https://nicolasbouliane.com/blog/print-preview-significantly-different-inspector-chrome

Answer (score 2):

You can try `-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact;`, which overrides the setting where Chrome removes background colors. This could fix your problem.

Comment: Doesn't seem to solve the issue unfortunately. I am still very confused why the print preview differs from the 'simulate CSS media print' setting. Shouldn't these be the same?