# Chrome Print stylesheet not working

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

I have a stylesheet that is working perfectly in IE, removing headers and footers and displaying my content in a more easy-to-print way. however when printing in chrome, it does not work. If i emulate a print media query in the developer tools it does.

I suspect this is because Chrome converts the document into a pdf before printing. Is there any way around this?

- in my html code, my css files are linked as follows:

`<link href="/css/form.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../content/PrintConfirmation.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print"/>`

as i said, this works perfectly in IE when printing, but in chrome when going to print, it doesnt.

Comment: adding your css/html would atleast give a bit better insight in your problem :) because right now i got no clue :)

Comment: Have you tried to add `type="text/css"` to the link tag for your print CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate question, See answer: [Chrome: Print preview differs from simulate CSS media print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529683/chrome-print-preview-differs-from-simulate-css-media-print?rq=1)

Particularly `transition: none !important;`

Comment: Welcome To Stack Overflow! This should probably be posted as a comment to the question and not listed as an answer.  Otherwise, you should post the relevant information from your link into your answer.

Comment: regardless of whether it is a question or not, its incorrect. my problem was that no styles were showing. It was a bug with chrome and was addressed

Comment: Great, perhaps you can answer your own question then? :)